# MISRA 5-2-1 rule requires postfix-expressions?

Tags: c++, misra

The rule 5-2-1 in MISRA-2008 states that

> Each operand of a logical `&&` or `||` shall be a postfix-expression. Exception: Where an expression consists of either a sequence of only logical `&&` or a sequence of only logical `||`, extra parentheses are not required.

And here are the examples, right from the document itself:

```
if (x == 0 && ishigh)      // Non-compliant
if (( x == 0 ) && ishigh)  // Compliant
if (x || y || z)           // Compliant by exception, if x, y and z bool
if (x || y && z)           // Non-compliant
if (x || (y && z))         // Compliant
if (x && !y)               // Non-compliant
if (x && (!y))             // Compliant
if (is_odd(y) && x)        // Compliant
if ((x > c1) && (y > c2)  && (z > c3))   // Compliant - exception
if ((x > c1) && (y > c2)  || (z > c3))   // Non-compliant
if ((x > c1) && ((y > c2) || (z > c3)))  // Compliant as extra() used
```

Could somebody point me where the **posfix**-expressions are there? They look as primary ones. I don't see anything like `++` or `--`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All primary-expressions *are* postfix-expressions. In these examples, the only postfix-expression that's not a primary-expression is `is_odd(y)`.

The [grammar](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram#nt:postfix-expression) for postfix-expressions is:

> postfix-expression:
>
> > primary-expression
> > postfix-expression `[` expr-or-braced-init-list `]`
> > postfix-expression `(` expression-listopt `)`
> > simple-type-specifier `(` expression-listopt `)`
> > typename-specifier `(` expression-listopt `)`
> > simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
> > typename-specifier braced-init-list
> > postfix-expression `.` templateopt id-expression
> > postfix-expression `->` templateopt id-expression
> > postfix-expression `++`
> > postfix-expression `--`
> > `dynamic_­cast` `<` type-id `>` `(` expression `)`
> > `static_­cast` `<` type-id `>` `(` expression `)`
> > `reinterpret_­cast` `<` type-id `>` `(` expression `)`
> > `const_­cast` `<` type-id `>` `(` expression `)`
> > `typeid` `(` expression `)`
> > `typeid` `(` type-id `)`

and

> primary-expression:
>
> > literal
> > `this`
> > `(` expression `)`
> > id-expression
> > lambda-expression
> > fold-expression
> > requires-expression